# Как сделать страницы сайта с динамическо-статическими div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Нужно так, чтобы страница была разделена на 2 части. Одна часть при скроллинге была зафиксирована на позиции, а другая (назовем её второй частью) скроллилась. А вот после того как вторая часть подошла к концу, при скролле обе части вверх уходили. [Пример](http://melaniedaveid.com)

Comment: Вообще-то ссылки вставлять можно, поэтому вставляйте. :)

Comment: а что мешает от туда взять код ? Не обязательно весь но в качестве ознакомления думаю можно

Comment: @lenov, ну мне бы хотелось копнуть поглубже. Чтобы знать в будущем

Comment: ну если про знания в будущем тогда js вам в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Страницу не ковырял, мои предположения - 
Левая часть в нужный момент становится fixed средствами js, и закрепляется.. а когда не нужно - по деволту.

либо, через absolute. Т.к. в любом случае - на каждый скрол нужно что-то обчислять. Для начала можете погуглить "position fixed по вертикали" либо "position fixed по горизонтали" конкретно это вам не нужно, но чтоб понять как на каждый скрол проводятся расчеты.

Answer (score 0):

Из закрома своих готовых вариантов. Думаю, "сегодня" можно сделать и как-то гуманне и короче, но как представление как сделать - сгодится:

```js
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  var labels = $('.forlabels'),
      labelsSec = $('.forlabels-section'),
      bottomOfLabels = labels.outerHeight() + labels.offset().top,
      bottomOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.outerHeight() + labelsSec.offset().top,
      topOfLabels = labels.offset().top,
      topOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.offset().top,
      isAboveTopSec = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabelsSec,
      isAboveTop = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabels,
      isBelowTop = $window.scrollTop() >= topOfLabels,
      isBelowBottom = bottomOfLabelsSec <= bottomOfLabels;


  if ( !isAboveTopSec && ((isBelowTop && !isBelowBottom) || isAboveTop)) {
    
    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked')
      .removeClass("sticked2")
      .text("Sticked");
  } else if (isBelowBottom) {
   
    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked2')
      .removeClass('sticked')
      .text("Scrolled Below Bottom");
  } else {
    
    $('.forlabels')
      .removeClass('sticked sticked2')
      .text("Not sticked ");
  }


});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one-half {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.one-half {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 45%;
    flex: 1 45%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 45%;
    min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.fbox{
  height: 1800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}


.forlabels-section {
   height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.forlabels {
  
  height: 100px;
  background: #777;
}
.forlabels,
.forlabels-section {
  width: 200px;
}
.sticked{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: inherit;
}
.sticked2{
  bottom:0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fbox">
  
  <div class="forlabels-section">
    <div class="forlabels">Untouched Column</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="one-half columned"> 
    </div>

</div>
```